# updating min value on the second column when the first column appears more then once

Tags: sql-server

[image]Im struggling with how to do this in one step.

I have a column with values which vary between 1 and +-20. Linked to this is a second value which is normally between 1 and 5.

what i want to do is when Number 1 values appears more then once then I need to update the value in column Number 2 to 99 but only the highest number in the Number 2 column.

I have added a pic to explain better. 
Basically id is unique, if value 1 appears more then once I need to update value 2 for where the value in value 2 is the highest value.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and how you would want to update that? (what the output would be after the update)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to find the row with the highest `No2` value and you can use `count() over()` to check if there are more than one row present for a `No1` value.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7453b/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  No1 int,
  No2 int
);

insert into YourTable values
(1, 3),
(1, 2),
(2, 1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with C as
(
  select No2,
         row_number() over(partition by No1 order by No2 desc) as rn,
         count(*) over(partition by No1) as c
  from YourTable
)
update C
set No2 = 99
where rn = 1 and
      c > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7453b/1/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from YourTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7453b/1/1)**:

```
| NO1 | NO2 |
|-----|-----|
|   1 |  99 |
|   1 |   2 |
|   2 |   1 |
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have added a pic , i dont think i explained it properly to start with , hopefully the pic helps.

Comment: Guys it worked thanks much appreciated. Using a loop with this solves my issue.

Comment: @user No, not much. I don't understand why you need a loop. Perhaps it would be clearer if you add the expected result to the question as well.

Comment: Hi Mikael, Im using the loop because this runs daily. there is one more field which is a date field.

Comment: @user5469 So, that means you can probably add the date to the partition clause and be rid of the loop. Hard to tell unless you update the question with what you really want.